# iOS Simulator 13.2.2 wallpaper looks strange

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Since I've switched to XCode 11 and iOS 13.2 suddenly my Simulator wallpaper looks a bit like there are only 16 Bit colors or too much contrast. Apps and Photos are looking normal, appears in light and dark mode, only the wallpaper. I've installed new XCode 11.2.1, resetted the Simulator, restarted my Mac multiple times. But all Simulators are looking the same (iPad, iPhones)

Did anyone experience the same?

Did I hit accidentally some settings (I 've tried to switch all available menu items like graphics quality etc.)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Click "Hardware" when simulator is selected and then click "erase all content and settings"

Comment: as described I've done that multiple times without any effect

Comment: Maybe "the hard way" Uninstall Xcode and reinstall.

Comment: Done also that without any effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Display and Text set in a simulator called "Smart Invert"

you can change it and wallpaper gets change.

[image]

Comment: Smart invert is off. Turning it on or off does not have any effect on the wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the wallpaper on the iOS 13 appears dark because of the new dark mode feature that has been introduced in iOS 13 and iPadOS 13. The operating system makes the wallpaper dark or dims it in order to make the background image easier on the eye for users who are using the dark mode.

But still the question remains how to disable "Dark Appearance Dims Wallpaper", because simulator doesn't have wallpapers menu in settings